# Are you allowed to solve an exercise from a book more than seven times?

Tags: copyright, licensing, germany

In Germany, apparently, you are allowed to make a "Privatkopie" at most seven times. Are you allowed to write down an exercise on a device using a note taking app more than seven times?

Does writing down exercises count?
Precisely, in math, when you solve an algebraic problem, you usually start by writing down the initial problem and proceeding from there.
Now that means you made one "Privatkopie"?

Now what if you some time later want to solve the same algebraic problem again, writing down the initial problem, ...

You made another "Privatkopie"?

I'm precisely talking about Germany, and books that the author told not to copy, ...

Comment: where did you get that "7 times" limit from? Also, you are making the strong (and likely unwarranted) assumption that a mathematical problem itself would be covered by copyright.

Comment: Don't solve the same maths problem 7 times! If necessary, solve (as many as needed) similar problems.

Comment: Easy! Always destroy one of the 7 copies before the 8th time.

Answer (score 32):

You can make as many "manual copies" of math homework for yourself as you like.

The seemingly arbitrary number of "7" came into being because with the invention and popularity of devices for copying, private persons could make copies without considerable loss of quality.

As it was impossible to control who made a copy and whom it was given to, a compromise was found: buying a copying machine (tape recorder, cd burner, dvd burner) or empty media (empty cassette tapes, empty CDs) came with an extra fee on top to be paid by the consumer, that would go to the copyright holders in general, with the assumptions that that would cover the "normal, uncontrollable, private between friends" copying. Like if you burn your mom a CD. Or gift your girlfriend a mix tape. Or copy a page of the book and hand out the excercise to your two study buddies.

So there was a [court decision](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privatkopie#Anzahl_der_Kopien) that "more than seven" was more than what you would normally consider a private copy covered by this fee. If you make more than seven copies of a cassette for example, it would be okay to assume that you no longer did that "for a close friend".

Obviously, copying something from a book as you describe, by writing it down with a pencil on a notepad, is in no way "a lossless copy". Even if you type it into an app, manually copying something into another medium is not lossless. Ever. It is also for your very personal use, you don't give it to anyone, not even close friends.

So yes, you can make as many copies as you like, for yourself. If one breaks, and you make another, that is fine. If one breaks every day and you need 700 over the course of two years? Fine. But if you made 700 exact copies to give them to your "700 closest friends", that is not how the law thinks "closest friends" work. That is where the arbitrary number 7 comes from.

Comment: "I consider anyone who gives me a gift of at least 10€ to be one of my closest friends!" - Also not how the law thinks "closest friends" work.

Comment: I notice the Wikipedia article you link to says that this “as a rule” comes into play when deal with copied handouts in education, and your answer deals mainly with the concept of ‘close friends’ – but is any distinction made for provably _personal_ uses? For instance, if I find a really lovely page in a book and make 5,000 copies of that page to use as wallpaper in my own room, without ever giving any copies to anyone else, would the more-or-less-rigid maximum of seven copies be considered irrelevant, or would it still count the same?

Comment: @Douglas If you were a *true* friend, you'd be adding a few more zeros to that number. ;)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Funny that you ask, because there was a case like that just now. As long as nobody sees your room *ever*, you are fine. If you let a close friend sleep there, you are fine. If you put a photo of that room online, *that is a problem*. The actual case was about a photograph that someone had bought as a wallpaper and put in a room and had put a photo of the room up on a platform for rentals. The seller of the picture had sold the picture, but technically, not the rights to reproduction and public display, which a photo of the room online constitutes.

Comment: @nvoigt That's a very interesting/intriguing case! Could you share a link? Would love to read more about it.

Comment: @user2705196 Yes. The formatting is horrible, but it is the official page, so what can you do... https://www.justiz.nrw.de/nrwe/lgs/koeln/lg_koeln/j2022/14_O_350_21_Urteil_20220818.html

Comment: Completely an aside but I'm now very curious how the fee is distributed to "copyright holders in general"

Comment: @nvoigt: From that description, I don't think there would have been a problem if the person had posted a photograph of the room to a social media site as a "Hey, check out my cool room" without any attempt to personally profit.  On a rental site, however, one could be perceived as using the picture to increase other people's anticipated enjoyment of the room, and increasing rental demand.

Comment: @supercat You may want to read the link I posted. While it was a rental, nowhere in the link does it say anything about commercial use or profit. The damages awarded were fixed sums, not parts of any perceived or real profit.

Comment: @Mr.Mindor https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauschalabgabe

Comment: @nvoigt: I don't understand German.  My point was that if someone had advertised "If you rent our room, you can admire our awesome wall containing hundreds of copies [or even one copy] of ___ picture", that may have fallen afoul of "personal use" allowances regardless of whether the ad itself contained a reproduction of the work, and I would think that the appearance of the work within the rental ad could have been interpreted as having similar implications that in exchange for the rental, people would be allowed to admire a copy of the work.

Comment: @supercat Yes, might have. But that wasn't the case.

Comment: @nvoigt The court report reproduces the photo 16 times. Isn't the court also guilty? ;) (Cue the stoning scene from Monty Python's Life of Brian.)

Comment: @Mr.Mindor: as author of a copyrightable work, you register that work with the relevant collection management organisation (e.g. as the author of a text with the VG Wort) who distribute the collected fees according to defined categories. E.g. for scientific articles in print journals the VG Wort computes annually from the sum of collected fees in the relevant fee categories and the sum of registered text "standard pages" the current payout per standard page of scientific text (2022: 10 €) and then distributes according to the number of standard pages registered by each author what they get.

Comment: @nvoigt: I managed to view a translation of the page.  Given " In application of these principles, the disputed photographs in their specific use cannot be regarded as insignificant accessories of the guest room. Rather, the disputed photographs are used to create a recognizable mood for the advertised guest room. The photos are a central element in the room design and are prominently placed on the back wall, which makes up the main part of the photograph posted on the Internet *for advertising purposes*", that would sound as though the fact that the picture was advertising a room...

Comment: ...available for rent was relevant to the decision, though without reading the decision in German I can't tell whether that would be a reasonable inference.

Comment: "manually copying something into another medium is not lossless. Ever" why do you say that? If the original info is only text and you type it in without mistakes then there's no loss. Mistakes would be loss but in that case "manually copying something into another medium is sometimes lossless"

Comment: @SkySpiral7 I think you missed the part of my sentence that reads "into another medium". Copying a text file perfectly into another text file is obviously the *same medium*, whether you do it by CTRL-C/CTRL-V or 13 hours of painstakingly typing.

Comment: @nvoigt taking a picture of a hand written note is a different medium and lossless. Typing a hand written note into a txt file would only lose the person's unique hand writing which isn't copyrightable. In the same way a photocopy may leave tiny bits of mistake ink and therefore not be identical but at that point you might as well take it to the logical extreme and say that because the copy doesn't use the same atoms it isn't the same and thus "lossless" has no meaning. My point is that if you are only interested in the text content it can be copied losslessly despite medium.

Comment: @SkySpiral7 Feel free to link me any indication that I misinterpreted or mistranslated the courts decision. Whether the courts decision is *correct* from a technical point of view is something that is really not a productive discussion here.

Comment: @nvoigt ah so you mean "the law always considers another medium to be lossy" that makes sense and is a reasonable legal decision.